# In codeigniter how to remove unwanted characters or symbols in string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

When i run csv  import using codeigniter  php i stuck with this mysql error

[image]

> Reason for this error is that unwanted characters or symbols in the string.

This is the CodeIgniter code I use.

```
$this->db->where('designationName', $row[$ex_start + 3]);
$q = $this->db->get('designation');
if ($q->result()) {
$id = $q->result_array();
    $designation = $id[0]['iddesignation'];

} else {
    $data = array(
        'designationName' => $row[$ex_start + 3], //this is the variable that get string 
        'designationDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'status_idstatus' => '1'
    );
    $this->db->insert('designation', $data); //this is the point that error occurs
    $designation = $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

**How I avoid this kind of characters or symbols ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do

```
$data = array(
    'designationName' => preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/','', $row[$ex_start + 3])
    'designationDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'status_idstatus' => '1'
);
```

> **Note:** This will allow plain text+numbers to save. No, any special chars will pass

---

**Edit 01**

If you need to allow some special chars (all keyboard chars)

```
 preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_~`\/@!$.%^#&*\\()+-=]/','', $row[$ex_start + 3])
```

---

Or you can use [**Escaping Queries in codeigniter**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)

1. `$this->db->escape()`
2. `$this->db->escape_str()`
3. `$this->db->escape_like_str()`

Comment: Thanks sir for you   solution.  I will check it and let you know.

Comment: Sir   Escaping Queries in codeigniter not working  but `preg_replace`  replace that chars  thing is  i have  to   add all  keybord symbols to  that  code to allow  to pass

Comment: @SupunAbesekara yes in that regex its only pass letters+number only. if you're allowing special char you can add them manually

Comment: Sir  i use like this  `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_~`\/@!$.%^#&*\\()+-=]/','', $row[$ex_start + 3])`  and it  work for me.

Comment: Happy to help :)